# Safe size for printing image from browser

Tags: print-design, artboard, size

I have an Illustrator document with A4 size and export it as PNG with 300 ppi for printing (you can see it [here](https://emotionathletes.org/images/dia1.png) in case it helps). On Safari and Firefox, printing that image from the browser with A4 paper results in 2 pages (whereas downloading it and printing from the operating system scales it to fit one page). I can print it on one page by scaling it down to 93% on the browser; when I scale the design down to 93%, I get the same problem. I also decreased the artboard size by 3mm on each side and tried a much smaller version with the same ratio (1.44, square root of 2), both giving the same problem.

What is a safe artboard size when printing directly from modern browsers?

Comment: Um.. **why** would you be concerned about printing from a browser?? Printing is a function of the **operating system** and you **can't** control that on every possible computer. If you wish to control size, use PDF, not PNG.

Comment: Note that scaling on browsers resamples the image so what exactly was the point of the extra pixels then. Leave margins, so make the image slightly smaller than a a4 so that the printer has space for margins.

Comment: @joojaa On the same artboard size of A4, I decreased the size of all artwork, down to 80%, which leaves a lot of white on all sides. The browser still prints 2 pages, albeit the second one is all white.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by printing from browser? Css set overflow to hidden perchance. Anyway browsers arent set up to handle this really.

Comment: @joojaa Some users might print the designs from the browser. I'd like them to print in one page and not two. The page to print is only a PNG image and has no CSS.

Comment: @miguelmorin - you can't control a users print settings when they print something. Those are user settings, chosen by the user, not by the browser. If operating systems were to allow a browser to change a users computer settings, this could actually be regarded as a security risk.  Another thing to note is that web browsers don't care one jot about ppi/dpi settings.  They completely ignore the setting. PPI/DPI is meaningless on the web.

Comment: I dont think you can solve this problem. There is no way for you to know what paper is loaded. There is no way for you to know what size margins the printer has. There is no way for you to control what size the browswer choices to send the image to the printer since you dont know what browser or OS is in place. There is just no standard that can control this.

Comment: Do you want printing from the browser to avoid giving too easily editable or distributable files? One can print to file, so this doesn't make any difference.